# javascript firing before its event occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, events, live

I'm trying to troubleshoot a rather large file where a javascript is misbehaving—a function is firing before it's event occurs. I know the event hasn't occurred because it's happening onload, and I don't have any onload events (just focus,blur,click,keyup which are binded to form elements). Is there a Firefox plugin/add-on or something that will give me a play-by-play of what javascript is doing what as it's happening? I have Firebug and the Developer Toolbar, but I didn't find that feature in them.

Comment: have you checked the body tag does not have `onload=` in it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, In firebug just go to the SCRIPT tag and add a breakpoint in the function that is being called unexpectedly. When it stops on that break point click the "Stack" tab to see where it was called from.